# practicing Core Data in Swift save method creates new entry everytime

Tags: swift

I've been trying to figure out how Core Data works with using Swift. I don't think I'm grasping the proper concept of the whole thing. I get that I need to be interacting with Context to store data to PersistentContainer, but it seems everytime I press on save button, the data is stored as brand new. I want it to be able to update the existing row. Below is my code. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  var editNotes: Note?
  let dataFilePath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
  @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  }
  @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print (dataFilePath)
    print (sender.tag)
    var new: Note?
    if let note = editNotes {
      new = note
    } else {
      new = Note(context: context)
    }
    new?.body = textView.text
    new?.date = NSDate() as Date
    do {
      ad.saveContext()
      self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    } catch {
      print(“cannot save”)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn’t look like a core data issue. You never assign anything to editNote so it remains nil.

Comment: and that creates brand new record every time I hit save button instead updating existing data? I didn't think I am working with editNotes with I'm trying to save

Comment: code updated, noticed missing a few lines from top

Comment: Don't you understand your own code? `if let note = editNotes` this condition will never be true since you never assign a value to `editNote`.

Comment: Unrelated but `NSDate() as Date` is pointless. Write `Date()` or just `.now` And replace `var new: Note?` with `let new: Note`. Yes, surprisingly the code compiles. The optional is not needed.